How to hide the default magnifier in PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDEA?
I am tying to hide this magnifier section in PhpStorm. But I can't. Can anyone please help me with this?
I tried to fix this in the settings screen, but I can't find anyone.
I face the same issue in the PhpStorm and Android Studio.



I am tying to hide this magnifier section in PhpStorm.

It's called "sticky lines" and it shows the start of the code block so that you can better see the context that is off screen.
"The sticky lines (or sticky scroll) feature enhances your coding experience by maintaining the visibility of parent elements as you scroll through the file, offering immediate context to your code."

To disable sticky lines
A few ways:

Right-click the sticky lines area in the editor and click Disable Sticky Lines (the screenshot below shows that).

Right-click the gutter area, select Appearance, and then deselect Show Sticky Lines.

Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance. Clear the "Show sticky lines while scrolling" checkbox.


https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-code-editor.html#sticky-lines

